# Why this promise.all does not work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bluebird

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var MongoDB = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));
var MongoClient = MongoDB.MongoClient;
var database = "mongodb://localhost/test";

MongoClient.connect(database)
.then(function(db) {
  var c1 = db.collection('c1');
  var c2 = db.collection('c2');
  return Promise.all([
    c1.count().then(function(count) {
      if(count==0) {
        return c1.insertMany([{a:1},{a:2}]);
      }
      else {  // what should I write here? 
      }       //
    }),
    c2.count().then(function(count) {
      if(count==0) {
        return c2.insertMany([{a:1},{a:2}]);
      }
    })
  ]);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

It just hangs there.

And what should I write in else part?

```
if(count==0) {
        return c1.insertMany([{a:1},{a:2}]);
      }
      else {  // what should I write here? 
      }       //
```

Comment: Well anything, but as long as something is returned. See the MDN [docs and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Your big problem here is `Promise.all()` does nothing all by itself, you need to resolve with `.then()` to actually execute anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess db.collection() returns a promise as well so you need to write something like this

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var MongoDB = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));
var MongoClient = MongoDB.MongoClient;
var database = "mongodb://localhost/test";

var insertIfEmpty = function(collection) {
  collection.count().then(function(count) {
    if(count==0) {
      return collection.insertMany([{a:1},{a:2}]);
    }
    else {  
      return Promise.resolve()
  });
}


MongoClient.connect(database)
.then(function(db) {
  var promisedCollections = [db.collection('c1'), db.collection('c2')]

  return Promise.all(promisedCollections).map(insertIfEmpty);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

If you need to populate the collections one at a time you can use .each in place of .map